# Rails 3 multiple parameter filtering using scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to do a basic filter in rails 3 using the url params. I'd like to have a white list of params that can be filtered by, and return all the items that match. I've set up some scopes (with many more to come):

```
# in the model:
scope :budget_min, lambda {|min| where("budget > ?", min)}
scope :budget_max, lambda {|max| where("budget < ?", max)}
```

...but what's the best way to use **some, none, or all** of these scopes based on the present `params[]`? I've gotten this far, but it doesn't extend to multiple options. Looking for a sort of "chain if present" type operation.

```
@jobs = Job.all
@jobs = Job.budget_min(params[:budget_min]) if params[:budget_min]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are close. Something like this won't extend to multiple options?

```
query = Job.scoped
query = query.budget_min(params[:budget_min]) if params[:budget_min]
query = query.budget_max(params[:budget_max]) if params[:budget_max]
@jobs = query.all
```

Comment: perfect - I was missing the `Job.scoped`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd prefer hand-made solutions but, for this kind of problem, a code base could become a mess very quickly. So I would go for a gem like [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search).

Comment: looks interesting, but there's gotta be a simple way that doesn't require a tack on gem

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put your conditionals into the scopes:

```
scope :budget_max, lambda { |max| where("budget < ?", max) unless max.nil? }
```

That would still become rather cumbersome since you'd end up with:

```
Job.budget_min(params[:budget_min]).budget_max(params[:budget_max]) ...
```

A slightly different approach would be using something like the following inside your model (based on code from [here](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html):

```
class << self
  def search(q)
    whitelisted_params = {
      :budget_max => "budget > ?",
      :budget_min => "budget < ?"
    }

    whitelisted_params.keys.inject(scoped) do |combined_scope, param|
      if q[param].nil?
        combined_scope
      else
        combined_scope.where(whitelisted_params[param], q[param])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can then use that method as follows and it should use the whitelisted filters if they're present in params:

```
MyModel.search(params)
```